# On using AUC metric in the kdd cup 2012 track 2, is it really reasonable?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I've used the test set solution file https://www.kddcup2012.org/c/kddcup2012-track2/download/KDD_Track2_solution.csv for kdd cup 2012 track 2,
and after this I just cheat (actually just a test) by make the predicted_ctr the ratio of #clicks / #impressions in the solution file for each test set instance, but still the AUC is low:

I'm confused, is it reasonable? Even seems like cheating, but I think the contrived ctr should match the solution file pretty well, if the contrived ctr is a good prediction, then maybe the AUC metric can not represent the prediction quality for learning algorithms in this problem.

```
AUC  : 0.478290
NWMAE: 0.000000
WRMSE: 0.000000
```

the corresponding python code snippet is like this:

```
num_clicks, num_impressions = read_solution_file(sys.argv[1])
predicted_ctr = [num_clicks[i]/num_impressions[i] for i in range(len(num_clicks))]
auc = scoreClickAUC(num_clicks, num_impressions, predicted_ctr)
print("AUC  : %f" % auc)
nwmae = scoreNWMAE(num_clicks, num_impressions, predicted_ctr)
print("NWMAE: %f" % nwmae)
wrmse = scoreWRMSE(num_clicks, num_impressions, predicted_ctr)
print("WRMSE: %f" % wrmse)
```

after some searches, I know how the auc is calculated, and some issues like this http://www.kddcup2012.org/c/kddcup2012-track2/forums/t/1545/calculate-auc

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

An AUC value of about 0.5 is **random**. A value of 0.0 would indicate the *perfect opposite*.

So there must be something wrong with your computation. Did you *sort* appropriately?

There are some situations where you should pay extra attention when computing the AUC; such as handling ties. If you naively sort your data, you might be placing all the positive or negative examples at the beginning when there is a tie, which is unfair. It's best to use a computation that actually goes diagonally then.

**Update:** I now see that they abuse ROC AUC in a somewhat hackish manner. It will still work somewhat, although it is quite ugly. What you lose is the nice semantic of AUC=1.0 being "perfect" and AUC=0.0 being "reverse". If the CTR is constant on this data set, the best you can do on this measure actually is 0.5!

I do however not see how you can get a value less than 0.5. Can you find a small example data set where this happens? Can you verify that all values are properly within the domain (e.g. no negative clicks!)

Comment: This case is handled, and the code snippet I use is pasted here http://codepad.org/QyUv43Ym , and the full code is actually here http://www.kddcup2012.org/c/kddcup2012-track2/download/scoreKDD.py

Comment: Print your `predicted_ctr` values. Are they (almost) *always* `0` by chance, because you did an integer division? Try doing floating point division.

Comment: Just for some issues, you may check the issue http://www.kddcup2012.org/c/kddcup2012-track2/forums/t/1545/calculate-auc and the my corresponding run sample http://codepad.org/1ZU1vx0k, and actually I used python3 and / defaults to floating point division, but I'll check that, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I'm beginning to see what the problem is. I believe one of the posters is right, and AUC just does not make sense to be used here. Usually, you need a *binary* attribute, e.g. binary class membership. Without this, TP and FP aren't really well defined. But you aren't predicting for individual pageviews, but averages here. The way AUC is apparently used here, predicting the exact click-through-rate should actually yield 0.5; but there are many bad solutions that yield the same score. In particular, *always* predicting the global CTR will yield 0.5, too.

Comment: I checked that the result is here http://codepad.org/vkE3hHDM (not run here), and it is indeed floating point division (I printed them).

Comment: Actually the first column in the solution file is num_of_clicks, not CTR (the code that reads the solution file treats it as CTR), so I think that is a bug, and after the bug is fixed I got an AUR of 0.759055 using my own method, and the result of "cheating" by this code http://codepad.org/WF4Wl0AH is very close to 1.0. But I think the AUR may not make full sense, because if the order of the predicted CTRs are the same (the values of CTRs do not matter), the AUC is the same.